# Why is this scene placed inbetween?

Tags: plot-explanation, mank

In Mank *(2020)*, Mank was invited to a circus-themed costume dinner party. He arrived drunk,
and sat at the head of the table. At that same party, Hearst and Mayer started
discussing "Marie Antoinette," and they both agreed that Marion Davis would
do the role justice. Then Mank breaks a glass by waving his fork.

**Then scene slowly fades to another scene, where Mank is sitting in a chair,
discussing his married life with his wife Sara. She tells him that she has put
up with his alcoholic behavior, and warns him not to allow anyone to call her
'Poor Sara' anymore.**

Then scene slowly fades to previous party scene where Mank gets up from his chair and
walks around the dining table. He says to the people that he has a great idea
for a picture about a modern-day version of Quixote.

Movie follows non linear screenplay and also location of the scene displayed
on the screen before every movie segment, but for this highlighted scene, it didn't.

Comment: "*Then scene slowly fades to another scene [...] Then scene slowly fades to previous party scene*" : are you asking about the technique (used for thoughts/dreams/flash-backs) or about the content of the scene?

Comment: @OldPadawan .... it seems clear to me that OP is asking what the flashback is intended to portray.  Seems clear to me, but I've not seen the movie, that this is a flashback, probably indicating a memory he has.  However I cannot answer because I don't know the significance of the memory.

Comment: Does this "scene" make sense if you think of it as a memory he is having at that moment he breaks the glass?